# Extract List Values using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Please help me extract the information from the below list code output. I want to extract the count i.e. "4" and text "bds" from the abbr from the below output:

```
[<ul class="list-card-details">
<li>4<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->bds</abbr></li>
<li>4<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->ba</abbr></li>
<li>2,482<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->sqft</abbr></li>
 </ul>]
```

I got the above output by running the below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
list_info = soup.find_all('div', class_='list-card-info')
house_one = list_info[0]
house_one_price = house_one.find('div', class_='list-card-price').text
house_one_bds_count = house_one.find_all('ul', class_='list-card-details')
print(house_one_bds_count)

#house_one_bds = house_one.li('abbr', class_='list-card-label').text -- working fine, so I commented 
it to incorporate it later into the code

#print(house_one_price) -- working fine, so I commented it to incorporate it later into the code
```

Also can you please guide me why I get an error of "*AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'content'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did 
you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?*" when I add .text in print(house_one_bds_count.text).

Will be very thankful. I am new to stack overflow so apologies if the formatting is not correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? I know for a fact that there are easily accessible answers to both those questions.

Comment: I am new to Python and I cant solve it. Can you help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extract data between html tags using BeautifulSoup in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426015/extract-data-between-html-tags-using-beautifulsoup-in-python)

Comment: @HarisSheikh _I cant solve it._ That's not a specific problem, though.

Comment: @AMC oh wow I didn't know this. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @picklu I somehow figured it out, I used the indexing. Let me try the method described in the link to improve. Thanks.

Comment: I made the below update to my code:

`house_one_count = house_one.ul.find_all('li')

house_bds = house_one_count[0].get_text()

house_ba = house_one_count[1].get_text()

house_sqft = house_one_count[2].get_text()`